# I want to insert a wifi switch into a light that is controlled by 3 switches I still want all the switches to work but need the wifi (alexa) controll

Tags: wiring, wifi

I have a central Hall light that is controlled from 3 switches I want to convert it to wifi (Alexa) control. One switch is at the front door and one is at the back door and one is in the centre of the hall This is the one I hope to convert to WI FI.
There are 2 sections in the switch I have  On section has a red wire to and bottom and the other section has a black wire to and bottom there are no wires from one section to the other. This is the switch I want to change to a wifi switch. I an not sure what gang wifi switch to get and how to wire it up.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. You're going to have to [edit] your post to explain what "There are 2 sections in the switch" means. How does the switch have "sections". While you're at it, please include clear, sharp, focused pics of the wiring behind all three switches (NOTE: Turn the power off at the breaker, pull the switches out of the mounting boxes, **DO NOT** disconnect any of the wires, take the pics, put it all back, turn the power back on).

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?  Also, how many watts of lighting are you trying to control here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to ignore the information about wiring, because any answer about wiring will change depending on what switch system you go with.  In a "light controlled from 3 switches" circuit (known as 4-way) you have two 3-way switches and one 4-way switch.  The 4 way switch has 4 wires, and the 3 way switches have 3 wires (not including grounds).

The way the smart switches that I'm familiar with work is they have a main smart switch that gets installed at one location and then a "remote" or "slave" switch is installed in the other locations.  Some remote switches (like from Leviton) get their power from the wires in the box, and require a neutral at all locations. *Edit: looks like Leviton does have battery operated remote switches now too...* Others (such as Lutron Caseta) use battery powered remote switches (that look just like a regular smart switch) so they don't require a neutral.  The Lutron remotes can be placed anywhere without cutting a hole in the wall since they are so small.

The brand that you go with is somewhat up to personal preference, but also depends on the availability of neutral wires.  Some switch systems require a hub, and some connect directly to WiFi.  The hub sounds like a bad thing, but in my experience the Lutron hub gives you a very solid, fast connection whereas switches that each connect to wifi are a litte more flakey (again, personal experience, just don't discount hub systems).

I also want to point out that you technically can just install one smart switch to save money (instead of replacing all 3 switches), but that would mean that *only* the smart switch would work and you couldn't use the other two.  I don't consider that an option, but wanted to mention it incase you had that idea.

Comment: When I say the switch has two sections I mean that there are two black sections like if you had a single switch but there are two side by side wired as I said one has red top and bottom the other has black top and bottom

Comment: @NormanMoor If the switch you are looking at has 4 wires, that will be the 4-way switch in your setup.  If all your switches work, you don't have a wiring problem.  The main takeaway from my answer is that you will be replacing ALL the switches that control the light, not just one.  So, you need to decide what brand of switch you are going to use and make sure it's in your budget.